# When does Magento decide to give a guest a new visitor_id? Cart gets empty sometimes

Tags: cart, magento-1, session, memcached

When does Magento decide to give a guest a new visitor_id? I noticed many entries in `log_visitor` table, and session_id often is replicated many times, and that makes cart get empty sometimes for some users.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is give a guest visitor id whenever `controller_action_predispatch` event is fire first time for a visitor .

On ***controller_action_predispatch*** event magento trigger function ***initByRequest()***

You can see the function at Class ***Mage_Log_Model_Visitor***

```
public function initByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this-_skipRequestLogging || $this-isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this-setData($this-_session-getVisitorData());
    $visitorId = $this-getId();
    if (!$visitorId) {
        $this-initServerData();
        $this-setFirstVisitAt(now());
        $this-setIsNewVisitor(true);
        $this-save();
    }

    if (!$visitorId || $this-_isVisitorSessionNew()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('visitor_init', array('visitor' = $this));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

**Seen config code**

```
<events
    <controller_action_predispatch
        <observers
            <log
                <classlog/visitor</class
                <methodinitByRequest</method
            </log
        </observers
    </controller_action_predispatch
    ...
```